# Cannot list tables (views, packages etc) from Oracle 11 database using sql explorer, but can see them using PL/SQL Developer

Tags: oracle-sql-developer, plsql-developer

I am connecting to oracle 11 DB.

When I connect with PL/SQL, I can explore all the objects :

[image]

However when accessing this same DB using Oracle SQL Developer, expanding the different objects results in empty list

[image]

Any ideas why this might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLDeveloper  shows tables that are owned by the logged in user. To see other users' tables, right click on connection ("dev" in your case), click "Schema Browser", and then select a user whose object you want to see.

Or directly query system views (e.g. all_tables )